# maximum possible value of the product

Tags: algorithm, tree, queue, priority-queue

You are given  integers 1,2,…,. Find the maximum value of (,+1,…,)⋅(,+1,…,) over all pairs (,) of integers for which 1≤<≤.

Input

The first line contains a single integer t (1≤≤10000) — the number of test cases.

The first line of each test case contains a single integer  (2≤≤105).

The second line of each test case contains  integers 1,2,…, (1≤≤106).

It is guaranteed that the sum of  over all test cases doesn't exceed 3⋅105.

Output

For each test case, print a single integer — the maximum possible value of the product from the statement.

Example

input

```
4
3
2 4 3
4
3 2 3 1
2
69 69
6
719313 273225 402638 473783 804745 323328
```

output

```
12
6
4761
381274500335
```

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. You are expected to show some effort in what you tried.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: You don't need to show code for an algorithms question, but you should show what you've tried, and specify what you'd like help with. I'm assuming you want help finding an efficient algorithm to solve this problem. It often helps to post a link to the source of the question, where possible.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have some input where the best answer is X. Among all ranges that achieve X, let R be the smallest. Then the min and max of the range must be at the endpoints, otherwise a smaller range would also yield X.

However, if R has more than 2 elements then it has some central elements which must be greater than the min of R. Shrinking R from the endpoint which has the min of the range would give us R' which has a larger min and the same max, so would yield X' > X, a contradiction.

Thus you only need to consider ranges of size 2.

tl;dr: Take the max product of adjacent members of the input.

```
2 [4 3]: 4*3 = 12
[3 2] 3 1: 3*2 = 6
[69 69]: 69*69 = 4761
719313 273225 402638 [473783 804745] 323328: 473783*804745 = 381274500335
```